# Compiling IBPP with VS2010 - linking issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, firebird

I have a C++ project that uses IBPP to access a firebird database. I simply do it by including the file "all_in_one.cpp" in my project, and all went well with both VS6 (yes, I still have some of those) and VS2008.

Now I am considering using VS2010. It is compiling ok but does not link. I know VS2010 comes with a new implementation of the STL, and the linking problem obviously is around the STL.

I have tried creating a new project with VS2010, just adding the all_in_one.cpp file. It is a simple project that does not contain anything else, and it still fails to link with the same missing symbols. I can't figure out what's missing, incorrect. I have tried linking to the same libraries as in VS2008 (including the path). Nothing is working so far.

Here are the errors:

```
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct std::_Smanip<__int64> __cdecl std::setw(__int64)" (__imp_?setw@std@@YA?AU?$_Smanip@_J@1@_J@Z) referenced in function "public: char const * __thiscall IBPP::DBKey::AsString(void)const " (?AsString@DBKey@IBPP@@QBEPBDXZ)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> > & __thiscall std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> >::operator=(class std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> > const &)" (??4?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc(void)" (?showmanyc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JXZ)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char *,__int64)" (?xsgetn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JPAD_J@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const *,__int64)" (?xsputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JPBD_J@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char *,__int64)" (?setbuf@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEPAV12@PAD_J@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) __int64 const std::_BADOFF" (__imp_?_BADOFF@std@@3_JB)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Xlen(void)const " (?_Xlen@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEXXZ)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Xran(void)const " (?_Xran@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEXXZ)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0?$_String_val@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@QAE@V?$allocator@D@1@@Z$0
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_String_val<char,class std::allocator<char> >::_String_val<char,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::allocator<char>)" (??0?$_String_val@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@QAE@V?$allocator@D@1@@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (__imp_?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall std::vector<class ibpp_internals::TransactionImpl *,class std::allocator<class ibpp_internals::TransactionImpl *> >::_Orphan_range(class ibpp_internals::TransactionImpl * *,class ibpp_internals::TransactionImpl * *)const " (?_Orphan_range@?$vector@PAVTransactionImpl@ibpp_internals@@V?$allocator@PAVTransactionImpl@ibpp_internals@@@std@@@std@@IBEXPAPAVTransactionImpl@ibpp_internals@@0@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
all_in_one.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your library/DLL is exporting some templated/STL stuff.

STL is not binary compatible among different compiler versions.

You need to use same compiler/linker/bitness to compile and link the DLL/EXE if STL/template is involved.

Comment: As I said, I have created a brand new project and just added the cpp files. All is compiling under VS2010, that was installed using the default install. I am not linking to anything specific (apart from the default libraries that VS2010 will use). Now, there are also VS2008 and VC6 on the same pc, that were previously installed. But as VS2010 was installed last, I would have thought that is would not be "disturbed" by the others. Also, this project is a simple console app, nothing fancy, no libraries, I am not even calling the code, just compiling it into the project for now.

Comment: Turns out this was the correct issue. One of the project properties was pointing at the wrong library, still on the VS2008 path. I will have to figure out where it is using this as a default…

Answer (score 0):

Remove the all_in_one.cpp from build and use the other files from core to build the library.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning linker errors 10 and 11 from the error list above, I have the following solution
(probably it fixes all errors).

Open the property pages of your project by right clicking your project inside the Solution Explorer and selecting "Properties".

Inside the "Property Pages"-window:

```
-->  open "Configuration Properties" from left menu
     --> select "VC++ Directories" on the left
         --> go to "Library Directories" on the right
             --> the corresponding string should contain a sub-string like
                 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib"
                 --> replace "9.0" by "10.0"
```

to make the changes working "re"build your solution (perhaps clean your solution first).